# How to set the size for each ion-popover

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, popover, ionic5

I have more than one ion-popover.I want to set the size for everyone.I researched this problem and I tried everything and I couldn't. However, I succeded to change the size globally, in *variables.scss*, but not individually. Does anyone know how to set every ion-popover? P.s I am using ionic 5 with angular

Here is only what I could have done, changing globally.
This I added in *variables.scss*

```
    ion-popover {
  .popover-wrapper {
   .popover-content {
     width: fit-content;
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ion-popover` has a property called `cssClass`. You can assign unique class to each one and then target it from anywhere as mentioned [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover).

```
 async presentPopover(ev: any) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverComponent,
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      event: ev,
      translucent: true
    });
    return await popover.present();
  }
```

Now you can do something like following (Notice `&.my-custom-class`):

```
ion-popover {
&.my-custom-class {
  .popover-wrapper {
   .popover-content {
     width: fit-content;
   }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: For who is struggling right now to set these popovers. You have to define for every popover a scss class like above, and then put every scss class in variables.scss

Comment: You could create a helper function in a service and call that function with unique name or class as an argument